# How to put two functions in one brace?

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

[image: here]

This is what I want. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 8):

```
$f(x,y)=
      \begin{cases}
        \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y)\ne(0,0), \\
        0 & (x,y)=(0,0).
      \end{cases}
    $
```

$f(x,y)=
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y)\ne(0,0), \\
    0 & (x,y)=(0,0).
  \end{cases}
$

See also: [the corresponding answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5025#5025) in the MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference.

Comment: Maybe add "\displaystyle" before the "\frac"?

Comment: Or `\dfrac`. That's all probably matter of taste. (Not really the heart of the matter here, the OP asked mainly about the "cases" part.)